# how can draw a kiviat diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-kiviat

How to draw a kiviat diagram like the following?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Comment: The original header of the question was not `how can draw a kiviat diagram? `. User Roboticist offered this header. The original header was (as far as I remember) `How can I draw this figure in resume?`. I think, this question is not duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
 \foreach \r in {0.5,1,1.5,...,2}{
 \draw (0,0) circle (\r cm);}
\foreach \t/\skl [count=\i]in {45/skill 1,90/skill 2,135/skill 3,180/skill 4,225/skill 5,270/skill 6,315/skill 7,360/skill 8}{
 \draw (0,0) --++ (\t:2)coordinate(\i);
\node at (\t:2.75) {\bfseries \skl}; }
\foreach \s [count=\i] in {0.96,0.8,0.93,1,0.42,0.4,0.2,0.43}{
\path (0,0) --  coordinate[pos=\s] (A\i)(\i);}
%\draw (A)--++(45:2);
 \foreach \j/\i in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7,7/8,8/1}{
 \draw [cyan,ultra thick] (A\j)--(A\i);}
\foreach \k in {1,2,...,8}
 \draw [fill=white] (A\k) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice. I like it, in particular.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much.

Comment: Yess! It worked! Thank you so much

Comment: With the white dot and the black border is better than the yellow. LOL.

Answer (score 9):

The `tkz-kiviat` package can do astonishing things:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[lattice = 5]{Skill 1, Skill 2, Skill 3, Skill 4,Skill 5}
\tkzKiviatLine[mark=ball,mark size=4pt,color =red](2,3.75,1,1.5,2)    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is correct, but I had so many unknown problems using tkzKiviatDiagram so I decided to use another approach:-)

Answer (score 5):

A small variation/improvements of [@ferahfeza](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499822/how-can-draw-a-kiviat-diagram/499835#499835) answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \r in {0.5,1,...,2}{
    \draw (0,0) circle (\r cm);}
\foreach \s [count=\i from 0, count=\j] in {0.96,0.8,0.93,1,0.42,0.4,0.2,0.43}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(Mod(\i+1,8))}
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (\k*45:2) coordinate[label=\k*45: skill \j] (aux); 
\node (A\i) [circle, draw, semithick, fill=white, inner sep=1.6pt] at (\k*45:2*\s) {};
}    
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(Mod(\i+1,8))}
\draw[very thick, blue] (A\i) -- (A\k);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]